# Displaying content from a grid field

Tags: solspace-calendar

We set up a grid field to capture a registration url and text for a registration button label.

{calendar:event_register:url}
{calendar:event_register:link_text}

We've tried several ways of trying to set the loop for the grid field without success. How do we display grid field data within a {calendar:events} loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While the Calendar:Events template tag may work similarly to the EE Channel:Entries tag, it is much more limited. This is because Calendar looks at event recurrence rules and populates the additional occurrences that way (rather than the recurrences actually existing in database). This inflates the counts and can take a huge hit on performance. In Calendar 1.x we had a large number of customers complain about performance issues, so in Calendar 2.x we sacrificed some extra Channel:Entries functionality in favor of huge performance gains. We did this by rewriting our own version of the Channel:Entries functionality and just included what we believed to be the more commonly used features. Unfortunately some features such as search parameter are not built in at this time.

In some cases, it works to embed a template with Channel:Entries tag to parse extra variables or conditionals. This could be done in the case of your Grid field. :)

Comment: So grid fields can't be displayed in this tag without an embedded template. Got it. I must have missed that in the docs. Thanks.